# TFS Build Process Publishes Web Site under different name than specified in Publish Profile

Tags: asp.net, web, build, tfs, publish

I am using TFS Build to publish a web site using a publish profile I have defined. The publish happens, but it publishes to a web application named after the web application project name, not the name I specified in the publish profile. If I publish using the same publish profile to my local machine, it does publish with the name I specified in the publish profile. I am using an administrative account in both cases, though it is a local non-domain account in the TFS build case.

The arguments being used are as follows (with pertinent details removed for security reasons):

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish /p:PublishProfile=MyProfile 
/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC 
/p:MSDeployServiceUrl=https://SomeName:8172/MsDeploy.axd 
/p:UserName=SomeName\LocalAdminDude /p:Password=SomePassword
```

and the publish profile itself looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This file is used by the publish/package process of your Web project. You can customize     the behavior of this process
by editing this MSBuild file. In order to learn more about this please visit     http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<PropertyGroup>
   <WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
   <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish/>http://Server/NameIWant</SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>
   <MSDeployServiceURL>https://Server:8172/msdeploy.axd</MSDeployServiceURL>
   <DeployIisAppPath>Default Web Site/NameIWant</DeployIisAppPath>
   <RemoteSitePhysicalPath />
   <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>True</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
   <MSDeployPublishMethod>WMSVC</MSDeployPublishMethod>
   <UserName>Server\LocalAdminDude</UserName>
   <_SavePWD>True</_SavePWD>
 </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Essentially, if my web project is named **NameIWantPROJECT**, I want it to publish to a website called just **NameIWant**. If I publish locally, that works, if I go through TFS with the above params, it publishes as **NameIWantPROJECT** instead of what I specified.

Comment: Check the `Build Defaults` tab in the `Build definition`. Maybe there is some other drop folder set than the one you want.

Comment: I believe I have discovered the answer. The Build Server is TFS 2010 and Visual Studio is 2012. It appears TFS 2010 does not support or recognize the PublishProfile property. Publish profiles are new to 2012 and support appears not to have been backported...

Comment: Glad to hear that you figured that out though. And it is always nice to see the answer still as you now did.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use /p:DeployIisAppPath instead /p:PublishProfile. That is, add following argument.

/p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site/NameYouWant"

It worked for me with TFS 2010.